# Why can we assign console.log to a variable

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am confused how we can assign console.log(`${tempCel} to ${tempFar}. What are we truly displaying?

```
const tempCel = Number(prompt("Enter a temperature in Celsius degrees:"));
const tempFar = tempCel * 9 / 5 + 32;
console.log(`${tempCel}°C = ${tempFar}°F`);
```

Comment: What to you mean by "assigning console.log" ? That's not what's hapenning here. You are just building a template string from variables you previously initialized, inside a console.log...

Comment: You're using template string. The ${tempCel} are just place holders and will display the variable value in the console. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: This is string interpolation / templating. "\`${tempCel}°C = ${tempFar}°F\`" is just "syntactic sugar" for `tempCel + '°C = ' + tempFar + '°F'`.

Answer (score 0):

To **assign** to a variable means to give the variable some value. It's usually done with = operator.

For example:

```
const variable = 5;
const variable2 = "Some text";
```

We cannot assign console.log() - it will always be undefined.

What you are doing is using a template literals inside the console.log()

You can learn more about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: "We cannot assign console.log() - it will always be undefined." - WDYM? `console.log = something` as well as `something = console.log` are very much possible.

Comment: There is a difference between something = console.log and something = console.log()